# programmatically create users in firebase node

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

With the latest node SDK, I'm unable to programmatically create users as I had done with older versions of firebase. I need this in order to create a pre-populated database for testing purposes. The node SDK does not support createUserWithEmailAndPassword. Any idea how to programmatically create users or get the uids of users from the db or programmtically sign in as a user with the web client's signinWithEmailAndPassword?

Comment: You can easily create the users in a little web script.

Comment: Yes, this is fine. However, the larger issue now is how to run a node app as a signed in user. The app is running on an IoT device and needs to operate on behalf of the user that registered the device.

Comment: Ah, got it. That's a use-case that we indeed don't support well at the moment. We're working on a release where it should be easier, but as usual: no promises or timelines.

Comment: Any timeline, even approximate,  so I know when to check back in again. Essentially, I'm looking for a node.js client SDK for firebase. It would seem that this should be important for firebase since more and more IoT device developers will want the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing your testing with a live firebase instance? It might be better to use firebase-server to do this type of testing: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/04/end-to-end-testing-with-firebase-server_16.html

This should make your tests run faster and you won't be reliant on an internet connection.

Comment: Yes, I'm testing with a live instance. Speed is not critical at this point although this local solution would be more cost efficient for large data sets.

Comment: Based on Frank's response, it seems like it might be the only way to do it even for small data sets right now?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the client-side auth and user management methods (including creating users) are available in the Node.js environment since the 3.3.0 release of the Firebase JavaScript SDK. The SDK should now be mostly isomorphic, but see my message on another thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/_6Rhro3zBbk/u8hB1oVRCgAJ) for the full details. Full release notes for that release are [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#3.3.0).

Comment: This is great! Especially as it solves my client problem when running node on IoT device. I'll give it a try and post back my findings.